# Install PhpExcell on the php project

Tags: php, phpexcel, php-5.3

I install the PhpExcel library in my project with composer :

```
"require": {
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-master"
}
```

I regarded in my composer folder : `composer/autoload_namespaces.php` :

```
return array(
   'PHPExcel' => array($vendorDir . '/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes'),
   .....
)
```

Now in my controller I do :

```
$objPHPExcel = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFile);
```

But I have the error :
`"Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found"`. I don't understand where is my mistake..Can you help me please ? Thx in advance

Comment: did you required the composer autoloader at the start of your script ? (or somewhere before you call PHPExcel)

Answer (score 0):

When you create `composer.json` file you should run

```
composer install
```

And next in your code you should include generated autoloader:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And it's all. Should works. You don't modify nothing in `vendor` directory.

Comment: The composer was installed earlier, with phpexcel I do only `composer update`

Comment: Maybe you should run composer update because install gets dependencies from composer.lock.

Comment: Do you have phpoffice directory inside vendor and it have library source code?

Comment: And do you include '/vendor/autoload.php' ?